# Saving output of kubernetes job as kubernetes secret in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create helm chart that will use Job to run a command that will retrieve some data from external server in "helm.sh/hook": pre-install.
What would be the best way to save data returned by this tool as Kubernetes secret?

Comment: Apart from shell + kubectl, the best way of managing K8s resources is through the go packages e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go. What did you expect your Job's runtime to be written in?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for any way to pass back the data from Job to helm but it looks it is not possible. I will try to use https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python and create Role and ServiceAccount that will allow this pod to create secrets.